# Unable to install features in servicemix docker image: ERROR http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.example/example/0.1/xml/example.xml

Tags: docker, apache-servicemix

I have run the servicemix image 5.3 as docker container in interactive mode and trying to install features below and hit it gives the below error:

```
karaf@root features:addurl mvn:com.example/example/0.1/xml/example.xml
Error executing command: Unable to add repositories:Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.example/example/0.1/xml/example.xml
```

I have configure one properties in etc/org.os4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg 
`org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.localRepository=/home/XXX/.m2/repository`

So it is searching in maven cental repository why it does not search into my localrepository which i have configure in above file.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM kaushal9808/jdk:7
MAINTAINER Kaushal Kishore Sengar 
COPY ./apache-servicemix-5.3.0 /opt/
VOLUME /opt/deploy/
EXPOSE 8181 8101 1099 61616 44444
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/bin/servicemix"]
```